# how to select the result using REGEXP in mysql,not contain a string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

MySQL does not support the Negative Lookahead. How can I find the result not containing a string using `REGEXP`.
I am using `'NOT REGEXP'` but the result is unexpected.

there is a 'Content' column in my table,i want to find the rows which the Content column contains '' label,but i still want some src to be excluded.

here is the sql:

Content REGEXP '.' AND Content NOT REGEXP '.(test.mywebsite1.com/|img.mywebsite.com/face/|test.mywebsite.com/phoneIcon.jpg).*'

but when the Content contain both  and   it works unexpected;

Comment: If you're asking for help it would be wise to post what exactly you're trying to match, what you've tried.. If you're looking to do an inverse match without using `NOT REGEXP` you can possibly use the caret `^` considered the negation operator inside a character class `[^ ]`, depending on what you need to achieve here.

Comment: You seem to be missing out on some first principles of regular expressions... `REGEXP '.'` matches *anything* containing at least one of any character.  Things containing a dot are matched with `REGEXP '\.'`

Answer (score 1):

Test your REGEXP on a known set, get that working, and verify it is working.

Then add the `NOT` to get the boolean inverse.

Note that a MySQL boolean expression will return one of three possible values:  TRUE, FALSE and NULL.

And note that `NOT expr` will also return one of three possible values: TRUE, FALSE and NULL.

When `expr` returns `NULL`, then `NOT expr` will also return `NULL`.

---

It's not really productive to attempt to provide any other assistance, absent an actual question and more details of what you are attempting to do.